# Creating a function table

Tags: excel, function, variables, functional-programming, formula

I am trying to figure out how to make a table that processes a formula I've created

The formula is 
     (Game Winning Percentage + 40) divided by 20 = players skill level

I'm trying to create a billiards league spread sheet where i can input the game winning percentages so that the computer will do the math quickly for me.

(p) Percentage, (s) Skill level

(p + 40) divided by 20 = s

If it is possible to do so I need help.

Comment: Can you show some codes you've tried?

Comment: Are you doing this in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no layout with your question, I'm going to provide one.

- A: Player
- B: Wins
- C: Losses
- D: Game Winning % (as %)
- E: Player Skill

**FORMULAS:**

```
D2=IF((B2+C2)>0,B2/(B2+C2),"")

E2=((D2*100)+40)/20
```

Keep in mind that the percentage is smaller than a 1.  It's a fraction, so I am multiplying it by 100 before performing any other math on it.  By failing to do so, all the results are very much the same.

[image: RESULT]

Comment: Thanks for your input and help.  Would you be able to tell me the program you used, or tell me were i can find a program similar?

Comment: I use Microsoft Office 2013 - Excel.  If you want a free program look into OpenOffice, or Google Sheets to name a few.